# Chrome Network Inspector: Is it possible to find the calls for a specific DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a table that gets filled with data received from an API call. Is it possible to somehow "lock" Chrome's network inspector on this element (= the table) and make it only show calls related to it and not every single one made by the rest of the page? Maybe this is doable with an extension?

Comment: You can enable the "Preserve logs" checkbox (if the page reloads sometimes), and add a filter in the upper left corner with regex (if enabled) - you'll have to write the regex in slashes i.e. `/[yourregex]/[flags]` - I'm writing a comment as I'm not 100% sure if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it's not possible to achieve, because:

1. The view and the logic are also seperated in (modern) frontend applications. So the app can request a JSON file from a server when it starts, and then passes those informations through the entire application (tables etc.)
2. A table itself is not calling the endpoint, and can be just generated by a function with the prefilled data.

The closest you can get is:

- Record screenshots in Chrome to see when the table gets filled. There you see which calls got made during this period of time:

[image]

- Afterwar you know what's the "name" of the call, you can put it in the filter/search field and reload the page. Afterwards, you will always just get shown the call you selected and is possibly responsible for filling the table.

---

Of course, you can also go by hand and say:

1. What is inside the table? Which information does it display?
2. Then go through the api calls and look for the information in the response bodies
3. Once you identified the call, filter it inside the chrome dev tools.

And if you want to go to the next level:

- Copy the call als a cUrl (via right-click on the call) and insert it in [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) and also install [Postman Inceptor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo?hl=en). Afterwards you can pass website calls (the one for your table) to Postman so you can have a closer look at it and also re-call it every time you need the specific call.

**To summarise:**
 Figure out which call has the information for your table, extract the call using Postman Inceptor and pass it to Postman with it. Then, you can analyse or do whatever you want with it.

Comment: This is what I have been doing too but I was kinda hoping I was missing some option somewhere. Thanks for the detailed guide nonetheless!